# Hiding field in dhangoforms which are generated from a model and saving it in the database

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

1] I have the following model:

```
class UserReportedData(db.Model):
  #country selected by the user, this will also populate the drop down list on the html page
  country = db.StringProperty(default='Afghanistan',choices=['Afghanistan'])
  #city selected by the user
  city = db.StringProperty()
  user_reported_boolean = db.BooleanProperty() # value that needs to be hidden from the display 
  date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

class UserReportedDataForm(djangoforms.ModelForm):

  class Meta:
    model = UserReportedData
```

2] The html code which will decide the boolean "user_reported_boolean" looks like follows

```
 '<input type="submit" name="report_up" value= "Report Up">'
 '<input type="submit" name="report_down" value= "Report Down">'
```

3] The idea is if "report_up" is pressed, the boolean value "user_reported_boolean" should be saved as true

4] The code that gets the call, when the user submits looks like follows

```
class UserReporting(webapp.RequestHandler):

  def post(self):
    #get the data that the user put in the django form UserReportForm
    data = UserReportedDataForm(data=self.request.POST)

    #need to find whether user hit the button with the name "report_up" or "report_down"
    # this is not working either
    if 'report_up' in self.request.POST:
        data.user_reported_boolean = True
    elif 'report_down' in self.request.POST:
        data.user_reported_boolean = False    

    if data.is_valid():
        # Save the data, and redirect to the view page
        entity = data.save(commit=False)
        entity.put()
        self.redirect('/')
```

Questions:

1] How do i hide the field "user_reported_boolean" from being displayed on the html form

2] How do i save this field "user_reported_boolean" in the database

Comment: Do you want the field to be in form but be hidden while display or you do not want it in the form atall?

Comment: @anand, yes i want the field "user_reported_boolean" to be present in the model but dont want it to be displayed.

Comment: @anand, I tried the response given by @Yuji Tomita below and was successfully able to hide a field in the model from the html page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### 1: Exclude the field from your modelform.

```
class MyModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
         model = Foo
         exclude = ('myfield',)
```

#### 2: In the unsaved model instance you have via `commit=False`

```
entity = data.save(commit=False)
entity.user_reported_boolean = True # False, whatever.
entity.save()
```

Comment: Thankyou @Yuji Tomita, this worked well. Thanks again for the detailed response